# reportlab how do I get left justified paragraph text to align right in table.

Tags: python, reportlab

My first thought was to use the `Paragraph` to align the text left, then use `TableStyles` to display that Paragraph on the right side of the column/cell but `TableStyle([('ALIGN', (1, 0), (-1, -1), 'RIGHT')]))` does not seem to have any affect. In my sample code I need the text in the RED boxes to be left justified text (like the text in the green boxes) but "stuck" to right side of the red box.

```
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet, ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.platypus import (SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph, Table, TableStyle, Spacer)
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_RIGHT, TA_CENTER


doc = SimpleDocTemplate("//cglvf01/tec/tmp/test/old/simple_table.pdf", pagesize=letter)

elements = []
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
style_right = ParagraphStyle(name='right', parent=styles[
                                    'Normal'], alignment=TA_RIGHT)

style_center = ParagraphStyle(name='right', parent=styles[
                                    'Normal'], alignment=TA_CENTER)

zero1 = """<font size="14">
<b>header</b><br/></font><font size="12">
line1 <br/>
line2 <br/>
line3 </font><br/><br/>
"""  

zero2 = """<font size="14">
<b>header</b><br/></font><font size="12">
line1 <br/>
line2 <br/>
line3 </font><br/><br/>
""" 

p1 = Paragraph(zero1,styles['Normal'])
p2 = Paragraph(zero2, style_center)


data= [[p1,p2]]


t=Table(data)
t.setStyle(TableStyle([('TEXTCOLOR',(0,0),(1,-1),colors.red),
                       ('BOX', (0, 0), (-2, -1), 0.5, colors.green),
                       ('BOX', (1, 0), (-1, -1), 0.5, colors.red),
                       ('ALIGN', (1, 0), (-1, -1), 'RIGHT'),
                       ]))
elements.append(t)
elements.append(Spacer(1, 12))

p1 = Paragraph(zero1,styles['Normal'])
p2 = Paragraph(zero2, style_right)

data2= [[p1,p2]]

t2=Table(data2)
t2.setStyle(TableStyle([('TEXTCOLOR',(0,0),(1,-1),colors.red),
                       ('BOX', (0, 0), (-2, -1), 0.5, colors.green),
                       ('BOX', (1, 0), (-1, -1), 0.5, colors.red),
                       ('VALIGN', (1, 0), (-1, -1), 'TOP'),
                       ]))
elements.append(t2)
# write the document to disk
doc.build(elements)
print("fin")
```